# Receiving a traceback on opencv opening images with python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, traceback

I am iterating through a large selection, and performing a selection of tasks on these images. The loop doesn't break, but when it is time to access the image, the variable returns None. I have tried to determine what makes an image incompatible but I cannot. My question is, how can I retrieve some sort of traceback when an image fails to load into OpenCV? More generally, what are the parameters of compatibility an image must meet and how can I test for them?

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
images = []
image_names = []
for image in os.listdir('images'):
    print image
    images.append(cv2.imread('images\\' + image, 1))
    image_names.append(image)

x = 0
while x < len(images):
    print x
    print image_names[x]
    print images[x].mean() # it breaks here with image[x] being None
    x += 1                 # so the problem must be where the image is opened
```

The documentation clearly stated that the imread() method would not report an error if it fails to open, only returns a None. 
I could then just test for this and exclude this image, but it is turning out to be alot of them, so I would like to rectify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

"so the problem must be where the image is opened" - exactly !

```
for image in os.listdir('images'):
    print image
    im = cv2.imread('images\\' + image, 1)
    if im != None:
        images.append(im)
        image_names.append(image)
    else:
        print "invalid:", image
```

Comment: It is not where the image is opened, I have confirmed this already. And I also stated that "imread() method would not report an error if it fails to open, only returns a None. I could then just test for this and exclude this image". My question was how I would find out the 'why'?